# How can I display some messages and redirect page after x seconds in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

In the Laravel framework, can I redirect a page after some number of seconds? Like redirecting to the dashboard page 10 seconds after a successful login.

Currently I use this function to redirect the page:

```
return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('success','Successfully login');
```

Using this redirects the page successfully, but the success message is not displayed on the page because the page redirects too quickly to the second page.

Comment: you need js [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)..

Comment: in laravel php code use in controller section so if we use javascript or j-query than css not applied for attractive massages,because of html code are in view portion of laravel, so we use flash massages features of laravel like dependency of flash ->with('success','msg');  so time delay possible in laravel redirect() metod?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<div class="alert-success alert-dismissible alertDismissible">hai</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $(".alertDismissible").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
       $(".alertDismissible").slideUp(600);
     });
})
</script>
```

Comment: how to config those code in laravel controller? this type of code or javascript/jquery easy to use in core php but how can i use in laravel?

Comment: need to use session like {{session('success')}}

Comment: return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('success','Successfully login'); in this code success is a session name but i dont understand how to use javascript for delay some of second

Comment: @if(session('success'))
    <div class="alert dark alert-icon alert-success alert-dismissible alertDismissible" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
      </button>
      <i class="icon wb-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
      {{session('success')}}
    </div>
@endif  use above js code

Comment: yes its working when massage display and stay on same page but if redirect example->after login than massage not display because of page quickly redirect in destination page...,in that type of case possible massage display like 5 second and page redirect? your javascript useful massage close after some of second but how to stay massage some of second and redirect page?

Comment: why u not use ur succes message in redirect page?means in dash board